# How to print out HTML: TableExtract results?

Tags: perl

A stupid question here. I am new to Perl and trying to use HTML: TableExtract  to extract some data online. I got numbers from a webpage but do not know how to print them out in a txt file. I tried to open an file but did not succeed. Here are the codes I use.  Thanks.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Encode qw(decode);
use Encode;
use Encode::HanExtra;
use Encode::HanConvert;
use strict;
use warnings;


chdir("C:/perlfiles/test") || die "cannot cd ($!)";

my $file = "tokyo.html";
use HTML::TableExtract;
open my $outfile, '>', "tokyo.txt" or die 'Unable to create file';

my $label = 'by headers';
 my $te = HTML::TableExtract->new(headers => [qw(number city)]);

$te->parse_file($file);

foreach my $ts ($te->tables) {
   print "Table (", join(',', $ts->coords), "):\n";
   foreach my $row ($ts->rows) {
      print $outfile join(",", @$row),"\n";
   }
}

close $outfile;
```

What is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "did not succeed"?

Answer (score 0):

Use `>>` instead of `>`. `>` will overwrite the last file everytime, so if your ending for loop iteration returns no value, you would end up getting a blank file. `>>` appends to the `EOF` of the existing file thus retaining the previously written data.

```
open (OUT,'>>tokyo.txt') or die 'Unable to create file';
```

So something like this might work.

```
open (OUT,'>>tokyo.txt') or die 'Unable to create file';
....
....
foreach my $row ($ts->rows) {
      print OUT join(",", @$row) . "\n";
   }
....
close OUT;
```

Also, your file handle is not quite right `my $outfile`. The file handle is supposed to "Label" the connection to the external file with the file handle used. In your case `$outfile` is a variable and contains no value! and hence no Label, and thus the file won't open. You have to prominently Label the connection of perl to the external file using somthing like `OUT` (as I did) or `OUTFILE` etc. and use this file handle through out the code to write, read close the file etc.